# Are Boolean expressions short-circuit evaluated in Google sheet formulas?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-performance

Suppose I have the following expression repeated in a long column:

```
=IF(OR($U2=""; COUNT(aHugeRange)=0); ""; SUM(aHugeRange))
```

I would like to avoid performing `COUNT()` and `SUM()` as much as possible to increase performance.

Will `COUNT()`, `SUM()` be [ever executed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) for the rows where $U is empty?

Will the following modification work differently?

```
=IF($U2=""; ""; IF(COUNT(aHugeRange)=0; ""; SUM(aHugeRange)))
```

Comment: Down-voter, please provide a comment, what is wrong?

Answer (score 4):

My test showed that `OR` and `AND` are fully evaluated, but `IF` is short-circuit evaluated:

```
Result   Formula               Notes
FALSE    =IF( FALSE; 1/0=1/0)  no error so I think 1/0=1/0 is not evaluated 
#DIV/0!  =AND(FALSE; 1/0=1/0)  error, so 1/0=1/0 is certainly evaluated
#DIV/0!  =OR( TRUE;  1/0=1/0)  same
```

So I should use `IF` where performance is important.